# Integrate $\frac{3x-4}{x(1-x)}$

Tags: integration

I am attempting Question 31B, 10 from 'Core Maths for Advanced Level' by Bostock and Chandler.

The question is to integrate $\frac{3x-4}{x(1-x)}$

I get: $-3\ln{|1-x|} - 4(\ln{|x|} - \ln{|x-1|}) + C$ which is also the answer symbolab gives.

However, the answer in the book is $\ln{\frac{|1-x|}{x^4}}$. I can't figure out how to get to this, either from the original integration or re-arranging the answer I have.

Comment: You have $\begin{aligned}&\color{white}=-3\ln|-1-x|+4\ln|1-x|-\ln|x|^4\\&=\ln|1-x|-\ln x^4\\&=\ln\frac{|1-x|}{x^4}\end{aligned}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $|x-1|=|1-x|$ due to the property $|a|=|-a|$ for all real $a$. Thus, $$-3\ln|1-x|-4(\ln|x|-\ln|x-1|)$$$$=(-3-4(-1))\ln|1-x|-4\ln|x|$$$$=\ln|1-x|-4\ln|x|$$$$=\ln|1-x|-\ln|x|^4$$ Now use $|x|^{2n}=x^{2n}$ for any integer $n$. Thus, $$=\ln|1-x|-\ln x^4=\ln \frac{|1-x|}{x^4}$$ using the property of logarithms $\ln a-\ln b=\ln\dfrac ab$.

Answer (score 1):

They are the *same* function. Note that\begin{align}-3\ln|1-x|-4\bigl(\ln|x|-\ln|x-1|\bigr)&=\ln|1-x|-4\ln|x|\\&=\ln\frac{|1-x|}{x^4}.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Well, we are trying to solve:

$$\mathscr{I}\left(x\right):=\int\frac{3x-4}{x\left(1-x\right)}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Let's use partial fractions in order to write:

$$\frac{3x-4}{x\left(1-x\right)}=\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{4}{x}\tag2$$

So, we get:

$$\mathscr{I}\left(x\right)=\int\frac{1}{x-1}\space\text{d}x-4\int\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{x-1}\space\text{d}x-4\ln\left|x\right|\tag3$$

Substitute $\text{u}=x-1$, so we get:

$$\mathscr{I}\left(x\right)=\int\frac{1}{\text{u}}\space\text{du}-4\ln\left|x\right|=\ln\left|\text{u}\right|-4\ln\left|x\right|+\text{C}=\ln\left|x-1\right|-4\ln\left|x\right|+\text{C}\tag4$$

Using log-rules we can write:

$$-4\ln\left|x\right|=\ln\left(\left|x\right|^{-4}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{1}{\left|x\right|^4}\right)\tag5$$

So:

$$\ln\left|x-1\right|-4\ln\left|x\right|=\ln\left|x-1\right|+\ln\left(\frac{1}{\left|x\right|^4}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{\left|x-1\right|}{\left|x\right|^4}\right)\tag6$$